# Javascript Bookmarklet - Gather Cookie from Browser

Tags: javascript, string, cookies, string-comparison

I'm using this as a bookmark in firefox, but when I visit the page and try to load the bookmark, it isnt doing anything. Is something wrong with my JS code?

With suggestion from user KURT, I was able to solve this by:

```
javascript: (function () {
    function getCookie(name) {
        if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
            c_start = document.cookie.indexOf( 'JSESSIONID' + '=');
            if (c_start != -1) {
                c_start = c_start + 'JSESSIONID'.length + 1;
                c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(';', c_start);
                if (c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
                return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end))
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
    }


    var thedc = readCookie("dc"); 

    if (thedc.substring(0, 2) == 'SP') { 
        alert(' in SP ');
    } else {
        alert(' in WC '); 
    }

}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to wrap it in a self invoking function.

```
(function() { /* Your code */ })();
```

Your getDC function also requires an explicit call, so this will need to be invoked.

```
javascript: (function () {
    function getCookie(cookieName) {
        if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
            c_start = document.cookie.indexOf( cookieName + '=');
            if (c_start != -1) {
                c_start = c_start + cookieName.length + 1;
                c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(';', c_start);
                if (c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
                return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end))
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    var thedc = getCookie("dc"); 

    if (thedc.substring(0, 2) == 'SP') { 
        alert(' in SP ');
    } else {
        alert(' in WC '); 
    }
}());
```

And compressed:

```
javascript:(function(){function e(){if(document.cookie.length>0){c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName+"=");if(c_start!=-1){c_start=c_start+cookieName.length+1;c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);if(c_end==-1)c_end=document.cookie.length;return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end))}}return null}var t=e("dc");if(t.substring(0,2)=="SP"){alert(" in SP ")}else{alert(" in WC ")}})()
```

Comment: This is outputting the session ID. I want it to hit either the if{} or else{}

Comment: that's because of the document.write you have. Remove it.

Comment: The only document.write is: t=document.write(e("dc"));

Comment: Exactly. I've removed it for you.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is its alerting the else statement, when that isn't true.

Comment: Is the IF statement correct to check for a value of "SP" in a cookie Name called "dc" ?

Comment: I don't have enough info here to comment on that. But look at your substring, you are only taking one character, but comparing it to two and expecting it to yield true :/ maybe try .substring(0, 2)

Comment: What information would  you need? I took a screenshot of the cookie output loaded ... I added substring(0,2) and it still alerts WC . What am I missing here?

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the question really, debug your script (even if that just means alerting values for now)... maybe try and alert(thedc); before the conditions. Send me your cookie.

Comment: Please see the attached image of the session above.

Comment: Something tells me its something wrong with the var t . Since the code thinks the var t is the session id

Comment: That;s because you're getting the session id... you need to rewrite the getCookie function to accept a cookie name.

Comment: Could you please show me how to get the name? Im sorry Ive been trying to figure this out for hours

Comment: I was able to get this figured out. Thanks